# jquery class selector applying event to all elements with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I am struggling with the search term and am not finding helpful information on how to solve my issue. I believe I solved this in the past and is quite common.

I would like to only apply the events and changes on a specific div with a common class name in my project.  The problem is that whenever I select and call event on one of these divs with the class, all the divs with that class are having the changes apply.

I thought adding specific ID's and using an ID selector would fix the problem, but unfortunately it did not.

Here is some of my example code:

HTML:

```
<div class="progress" id="encode">
    <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" id="encode_progress" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="100">

   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#encode").fadeIn("fast");
$('#encode_progress').progressbar({
    display_text: 'center', 
    use_percentage: false, 
    refresh_speed: 10,
    done: function($this) { $this.html('TWEET ENCRYPTED'); 
    // $(".checkTweet").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".newTweet").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Secod Div that is also running on the same click:

HTML

```
<div class="progress" id="decode">
    <div class="progress-bar six-sec-ease-in-out" id="decode_progress" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="100">                
        </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#decodeSubmit').on("click", function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("#decode_form").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#decode").fadeIn("fast");
        $('#decode_progress').progressbar({
            display_text: 'center', 
            use_percentage: false, 
            refresh_speed: 10,
            done: function($this) { $this.html('TWEET ENCRYPTED'); 
            // $(".checkTweet").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".newTweet").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });

})
```

The root of the problem is with both of these calls:

```
$("#decode_progress").progressbar();

$("#encode_progress").progressbar();
```

When I run this in the console it returns the same div (even though I have two of them).  This is being ran in two different places when called on.  I thought selecting by id would only run the one associated with that id, but this isn't the case.

I know very little about $(this) but I have a feeling I have to use that.  Once again, I have been trying to find the right search terms to push me in the right direction but everything I am finding so far isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that if you make a JSFiddle, you'll answer your own question. jsfiddle.net

Comment: Is there a search term you could possibly point me to? I'm having a very hard time recreating the environment in jsFiddle compared to my local. Here is my current progress: http://jsfiddle.net/rparz7qf/

Comment: @HelloWorld, [Fixed your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cg0udxj2/). It seems to be working to me.